# How to tell using T-SQL whether a SQL server database has the TRUSTWORTHY property set to on or off

Tags: sql-server

How to tell using T-SQL whether a SQL server database has the TRUSTWORTHY property set to on or off

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In SSMS:

Right click over the database, Properties, Options last record under Miscellaneous

In T-SQL:

```
select is_trustworthy_on from sys.databases  where name = 'dbname'
```